# how Can I partition a drive on Ubuntu without starting the system?

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I have all of my hard drive’s storage running on Ubuntu. My goal is to partition the drive. I know that I have to unmount it. But I can’t, because all the data is attached to the system and it is not possible to unmount a system which you are trying to edit partitions with. Is there any way to part hard drives without starting the OS?

Comment: Please explain in more detail, what it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a bootable drive on removable media (e.g. USB stick) - making sure that it includes a partitioning tool - and then boot from that.

To create a boot disk, you should be able to download a boot image suitable for writing to a USB stick - either with 'dd' command, or using Ubuntu's "Startup Disk Creator" tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. Create an Ubuntu bootable USB drive on [Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) or on [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0).
2. Boot from your USB by [changing the boot order](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#3) or whatever you did when you installed Ubuntu in the first place.
3. You should eventually be greeted to a screen that looks like this:
   [image]
4. Press Try Ubuntu (The system should now boot in to Ubuntu).
5. Press the icon in the left-bottom corner to view all applications.

[image]

6. Now search for a program called GParted.
   [image]
7. Once the program launches follow [this guide](https://www.lifewire.com/use-gparted-to-partition-hard-drive-2205693) to perform the configuration you are looking for.